# how to play multiple swf's in one flash player?

Tags: asp.net, flash, apache-flex

is there any way how to play multiple swf's in one flash player on ASP.net? As it needs to change the video being played as soon as a button is clicked. 
Thanks alot 
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

You can load external .swf files using the `Loader` class.

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.[yourdomain].com/externalSwf.swf");
var loader:Loader = new Loader()
loader.load(request);
addChild(loader);
```

You may also use `Event.COMPLETE` to check when the swf has finished loading.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Working_with_MovieClips_7.html

Comment: Cant it be done from asp.net by means of c# or javascript as i need that on runtime the vid changes accodring to the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't understand the question exactly then.

If you want to embed .swf files using javascript, I'd recommend you to use swfobject.

I made an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZGGCj/

swfobject is documented pretty well here:

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject